# sinon.restore in one file restores any top level stubs in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, stub

Service1:

```
const { Service2 } = require('../Service2.js');

const func1 = () => {
  const result = Service2.func2();
  return result;
}

const Service1 = { func1 };
module.exports = { Service1 };
```

Test for Service1:

Note that I need to test Service1.func1 which internally depends on Service2.func2, hence i would like to stub Service2.func2

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { Service2 } = require('../Service2');

const func2stub = sinon.stub(Service2, 'func2');

// import Service1 after stubbing Service2.func2, so that it uses the stubbed version of func2
const { Service1 } = require('../Service1');

describe('Service1 Tests', () => {
  it('should return some result on calling func1', () => {
    func2stub.returns(true);
    expect(Service1.func1()).to.equal(true);
  }
}
```

This works fine on its own.
But If I have another unrelated test file which calls sinon.restore() in its lifecycle, my Service1 tests start calling the actual implementation of Service2.func2 instead of the stub.

// Another test file

```
...
...
describe('some other tests', () => {
  afterEach(() => { sinon.restore(); }
  it('should ...', () => {
    ...
  }
}

...
```

I have debugged this by commenting out the sinon.restore , and by running just the Service1 tests in isolation.

During my debugging, a workaround that I found for this is to move the stubbing from the top level to before lifecycle in the Service1 tests

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');

let Service1;
let func2stub;

describe('Service1 Tests', () => {
  before(() => {
   const { Service2 } = require('../Service2');
   func2stub = sinon.stub(Service2, 'func2');
   // import Service1 after stubbing Service2.func2, so that it uses the stubbed version of func2
   Service1 = require('../Service1').Service1;
  }

  it('should return some result on calling func1', () => {
    func2stub.returns(true);
    expect(Service1.func1()).to.equal(true);
  }
}
```

This works fine, and is not impacted by the sinon.restore in the other file.

Any pointers to understand why this happens and the proper solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sinon` provides a default [sandbox](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/sandbox/) global to the module, which means everything in the default sandbox is restored when `sinon.restore()` is called.

It's possible to use `sinon.createSandbox()` to create a more granular sandbox relevant to the service, or test suite, or at whatever level you want to `restore`.

```
describe('tests', function(){
  
  let sandbox;

  before(function(){
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox({})
  })

  afterEach(function(){
    sandbox.restore()
  })

  it('should test', function(){
    sandbox.spy(x)
  })

}
```

mocha has two stages to a run

1. Setting up the tests to run
2. Running the tests

Anything outside of a `before`/`after`/`it` runs immediately during the setup phase.

```
Read test js files to build test run.
Traverse `describe` functions, running the attached callback function. 
Schedule `it` `before` `after` functions for test run. 
- Read Blah tests
- Read Service1 tests < Service2 stub setup here
- Read Service2 tests

Execute test run
- Run Blah tests  < sinon.restore() removes service2 stub.
- Run Service1 tests
- Run Service2 tests
```

So mocha has a complete picture of what tests can run, before they run.

Comment: sure, but what might be the reason for another test restore to impact things before i stub things in Service1 test? and why does that not happen when I move stubs to before()

Comment: That Service2 stub setup is running before _any_ tests start. I'll add some detail about mochas test setup.